# Showing a hidden gif on hover

Tags: html, css, hidden, animated-gif

Im trying to figure out how to get a hidden gif to display when the user hovers over the 'preview' text.

Atm my code looks like this:

```
<div class="hover_img">
    <a href="#">Preview<span><img src="/preview-images-gifs/gif2.gif" alt="image" height="100" /></span></a>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.hover_img a { position:relative; }
.hover_img a span { position:absolute; display:none; z-index:99; }
.hover_img a:hover span { display:block; }
```

I've been playing around with it for a little while, and the closest I've gotten is displaying the alt text.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: IGNORE THIS. It turns out i was just missing a . in front of the image src

Comment: You can/should delete your question.